# Context Free Grammar for a 3-variable language

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have to create a CFG for the following language:

$$\left\{ 0^i1^j2^k \mid i\ne j \space OR \space j\neq k \right\}$$

My idea is the following:

$$S→0S1S2S | AB |AC | BC | A | B | C$$
$$A→0A | 0$$
$$B→1B | 1$$
$$C→2C | 2$$

First I create a situation where all the letters are "equal" and also that there is at least $1$ instance of each letter.
Then I have the conditions:

**To create $j≠k→$**

```
if j>k create AB
if k>j create AC
```

**To create $i\ne j$**

```
if i>j create AC
if i<j create BC
```

I can also create only "advantage" for $0/1/2$ if I go to $A$ $B$ or $C$ alone.

Is my idea correct?

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 1):

Currently your grammar produces strings not in the language, e.g. 021021. I would suggest a different approach.

**Hint:**

- Split your language into 4 (partially overlapping) cases:

  1. $(i < j)$
  2. $(i > j)$
  3. $(j < k)$
  4. $(j > k)$
- The overlaps do not cause you any problems.
- For the first case $(i < j)$ it is enough to generate $0^i1^i11^x2^y$ for any $i, x, y$, other cases are similar.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you! What if I added an $S$ in the grammer like that: 
$$S→0S1S2S | ASB |ASC | BSC |  A | SB |  SC$$
$$A→0A | 0$$
$$B→1B | 1$$
$$C→2C | 2$$

Comment: @Alan You can still generate strings like "001020".